# Можно ли добавить метку на карту, не отрисовывая карту по новой?

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

Всем привет, у меня отрисовывается карта в файле **shop_maps.js**

```
ymaps.ready(init);
function init(){
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        zoom: 7
    });
}
```

А сама метка должна отрисовываться по нажатию кнопки в файле **shops.js**

```
$('.sklad').click(function () {
                var result = $(this).text();
                result = result.split(' ');
                console.log(result);
                sklad = result[1] + ' ' + result[2] + ',' + result[3];
                city = result[1];
                myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
                    geometry: {
                        type: "Point",
                        coordinates: [55.8, 37.8]
                    }
                });
                myMap.geoObjexts.add(myGeoObject);
            });
```

Однако он мне пишет *myMap is not defined*, хотя карту он отрисовывает нормально.
Можно ли добавлять метку на карту так, чтобы не создавать карту каждый раз при нажатии кнопки (то есть не вызывать new ymaps.Map()) и если можно, то как это сделать?

Comment: Наверное потому что в момент вешания слушателя карты ещё нет. Вам надо слушатель пихнуть в ф-ию `init`

Answer (score 0):

Как один из вариантов решил вопрос тем, что прописываю функции javascript внутри **function init()**:

```
ymaps.ready(init);
function init(){
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        zoom: 7
    });
    $('.sklad').click(function () {
                myMap.geoObjects.removeAll();
                var result = $(this).text();
                result = result.split(' ');
                ...
    }
```